# Pricing Tables in Avada Template - Adding links to columns

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

Pricing Tables looks perfect before I add `<a href=""></a>` tags to specific columns in Avada Template. Then, everything falls apart.

You can check it what it looks like after here - pahomas.pl/strony-internetowe-2/ and before (different data but the same columns) - pahomas.pl/strategiczne-pozycjonowanie-stron-2/

Links to screenshots:

### Bad

[image: Bad image]

### Good:

[image: Good image]

Here's a PHP code from this table WITH a `href` tags.

```css
<a href="http://pahomas.pl/strony-internetowe-3/"><div class="panel-wrapper fusion-column column col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 fusion-pricingtable-column"><div class="panel-container"><div class="fusion-panel">

...

</div></div></div></a>
```

Comment: Sure, I got it.

Bad: 
One link:http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b849jbj98 
Second link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/7163407?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1422196493&Signature=9CrRSTRxVcD2suG%2BnJ9vT3SENhE%3D&tag=01-2300-20
Good: 
One link:http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a449jbncc
The other link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/7163411?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1422196496&Signature=Oxfaatlh4bscosPHzUyWa70l%2BCE%3D&tag=01-2300-20

Comment: @halfer, I'd love to but I need at least 10 points of reputation to post images... Once, I got them, I would do this.

Comment: Check the images now, should be OK?

Comment: At a guess, there's some floated left whitespace after each `div` column - do a select all in your HTML to see if there's anything that is pushing those subsequent columns down. Hmm, in fact if links are the problem, have a look in your CSS explorer to see if there is any unintended properties that have been accumulated that you do not intend to apply. Sometimes themes add CSS with insufficient specificity, and they become a pain to customise.

Comment: @halfer - Awesome, thank you for images.

I'm looking for what you told me. I'll send you a feedback as soon as I find something.

Comment: @halfer - Could you explain it to me what does it mean to 'look at my CSS explorer'. Do you mean a style (.css) file?

Comment: In your browser (e.g. Firefox) you can switch on an 'inspector' panel to see what properties a particular tag has acquired by virtue of its classes/id/parents/siblings etc. It is the standard way of checking if your CSS definitions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution to my problem and I decided to share it if anyone had the same.

Comment: I still cannot post images, if anybody from the Mod Team could post this image here? Here's the solution shown on the picture.

s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/7165019?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1422217802&Signature=Dode0PJ1bRCF%2BKXqkgLEBLpYUuw%3D&tag=01-2300-20

awesomescreenshot.com/09149kkb0d

The `<a href= attribute` needs to be AFTER pricing_column shortcode and according to this rule, `</a>` needs to be BEFORE the closing of pricing_column.

The problem I've got was because the url was outside of this tag.

Now it works like it was shown above in a 'good' example - you can check it here and compare to the php code I has shown you above: http://goo.gl/ZRE7Ly

EDIT: I thought it worked but unfortunately, it was not. I reported it to Avada Support and they told me it doesn't work and they don't plan to implement it... :(